# How to get log file name form my application. properties file

Tags: java, log4j

Following are the files:

application.properties

```
log.name.error=error.log
log.name.warn=warning.log
```

log4j.xml

```
<appender name="allLog" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="../Framework/logs/log.log" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p - %m%n [%c:%M] (%F:%L)%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

I do not want to hard code the file name (`log.log`) instead I want to get the file name from application.properties file.

Comment: Are you using spring mvc?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. I am using spring framework. i have defined the dynamic values in xyz.properties file and specified xyz.properties file in the spring.xml. My query is, am i doing the right thing? will the log4j.xml will pick the values from .properties file?

Answer (score 0):

If your `properties` file is loaded into the `classpath`, then you can use the property placeholder to access it.

```
<param name="File" value="../Framework/logs/${log.name.error}" /> <!-- ${property placeholder} -->
```

Comment: I have tried it but its not creating log file giving exception FileNotFoundException

Comment: its my java app and there is Resources.Properties package and its contain my application.properties file and i have put my log files name as value in it, and i just wanted that when i log anything it read form properties file and get that file name put into log4j.xml file